# Unable to get Lat Long in background and after mobile screen lock. Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.android

I am not getting current latitude and longitude in background and after mobile screen lock .
permission

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation with Android, especially post Android v8.0, If you check the [following document](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background) from android it says the following:

> In many cases, your app can replace background services with JobScheduler jobs. For example, CoolPhotoApp needs to check whether the user has received shared photos from friends, even if the app isn't running in the foreground. Previously, the app used a background service which checked with the app's cloud storage. To migrate to Android 8.0 (API level 26), the developer replaces the background service with a scheduled job, which is launched periodically, queries the server, then quits.

> Prior to Android 8.0, the usual way to create a foreground service was to create a background service, then promote that service to the foreground. With Android 8.0, there is a complication; the system doesn't allow a background app to create a background service. For this reason, Android 8.0 introduces the new method startForegroundService() to start a new service in the foreground. After the system has created the service, the app has five seconds to call the service's startForeground() method to show the new service's user-visible notification. If the app does not call startForeground() within the time limit, the system stops the service and declares the app to be ANR.